# Diagram arranging algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, eclipse-plugin

I need an algorithm or preferably a library, that will assist with arranging a diagram. I can already draw my diagrams, I just need arranging.

A diagram consists of one or more different sized rectangles, they may be connected. Some rectangles must have fixed positions, and the goal is to minimize total connection length. For example, [this diagram](http://s7.postimg.org/onc77agt7/diagram.jpg) where red squares have a fixed existing position, and where green squares should be positioned to minimize total connection length.

An optimal scenario is for me to input a graph, where nodes are rectangles and edges are connections. Nodes would have a certain size and possibly a fixed position. The output will be a set of XY coordinates.

I would like to know either an algorithm or library for such a task, thank you.

I have already looked briefly at JUNG and Graphviz, but I fail to see how they might solve my problem. Also, the final program will be an Eclipse plugin, so I would like to be able to easily bundle any external dependencies.

Comment: So you are looking for a graph layout algorithm, but the ones in JUNG didn't do what you wanted? Is there some specific layout that you wanted?

Comment: With JUNG, I don't see how to specify that some rectangles have fixed positions. I am after something like [this](http://s7.postimg.org/onc77agt7/diagram.jpg). Here, all the red squares have fixed (x-axis at least) locations, and the green ones should then be placed for shortest total connection length.

Comment: Ah, so you need a *specific* layout algorithm, not just any old one. The red squares have an existing layout, which are a constraint on the layout of the green ones. You might be better off altering your question to better describe this particular requirement :)